# How do I enable Scrollbars on a UWP GridView

Tags: xaml, gridview, uwp

I have a UWP where I am loading from an XML file and showing it in a GridView and I am trying to enable Scrollbars in a way that allows me to stack and wrap items in all the available space like in the image below. The problem that I am having is that I cannot figure out how to enable the scrollbars so that I can scroll the boxes until I get to the end of the list.

[image]

So far I have got it to do what you see in the picture, which is wrapped the way I want but it fills all the available space and doesn't allow you to scroll vertically or horizontally (I only want to scroll one way but I have tried to see if I could go either way). Through a lot of trial and error I was able to get it to scroll one row or one column at a time to the end of the list but that is not the desired result either. Here is where I am with the XAML right now (trimmed down version of the screen shot).

```
<GridView x:Name="DataGrid1">
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"
                            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Width="270"
                    Height="200"
                    Margin="5"
                    BorderBrush="Black"
                    BorderThickness="2">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                Background="#87CEFA">
                        <TextBlock Margin="2"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    FontSize="16"
                                    FontWeight="Bold"
                                    Text="{Binding Company}" />
                    </StackPanel>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Margin="2"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                FontWeight="Bold"
                                Text="Code: " />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Margin="2"
                                Text="{Binding Code}" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

So what do I need to do to enable the scrollbars the way that I want?

Answer (score 7):

Make sure your GridView is in a Grid and not a StackPanel. It does not expand in a StackPanel. 
To make it scroll in a StackPanel you have to specify the height of the GridView. This was the issue with mine :)

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge gridviews that are not showing scrollbars automatically are due to stackpanel's presence. So my solution here is to try remove stackpanel what so ever, and if I find the stackpanel that's responsible replace it with other kind of panel and work my way back up. It's totally a brute force kind of approach but it works most of the time.
And another piece of advice. In that process of replacing the stackpanel try to replace it with grid and try to divide it's rows and columns with widths and heights set to auto or star sizing instead of specifying it with actual numbers to see if it works this way. If it works then work your way up speicifying it with actual numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem, in the definition of the `ItemsWrapGrid` you have:

```
 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
```

this is going to mean that even if the scrollbar is shown it wont work.

Remove this line and you should get a working scrollbar.

Comment: I tried that but it still just fills up the space. Neither scrollbar is visible regardless of setting the IsVisible props on them.

Comment: @BukHix - the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemswrapgrid) clearly implies that it should "just work". Perhaps try with a simpler `ItemTemplate` (just a single `TextBlock`?) first and see if that works. Then add one thing at a time until it fails and try to work out why adding that thing causes the problem.